# CKEditor incompatibility between Justify and Color Button plugins

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor v4.5.8. I want to display 2 different plugins:

```
justify
colorbutton
```

I am able to get one or the other to display but not both at the same time.

When I have this in my `config.js`, then `colorbutton` displays but not `justify`:

```
config.extraPlugins = 'justify';
config.extraPlugins = 'button';
config.extraPlugins = 'panelbutton';
config.extraPlugins = 'colorbutton';
```

When I have this, then `justify` displays but not `colorbutton`:

```
config.extraPlugins = 'button';
config.extraPlugins = 'panelbutton';
config.extraPlugins = 'colorbutton';
config.extraPlugins = 'justify';
```

Any insight welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting one `config.extraPlugins` setting with another. All [`config.extraPlugins`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-extraPlugins) should be listed in one declaration, as in:

```
config.extraPlugins = 'justify,button,panelbutton,colorbutton';
```

Also make sure that all additional plugins are actually included in your CKEditor package.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you.